# Trying to parse a string value from an API a JSON object into a struct as an Int

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to Swift and I have data I'd like to call from an API through JSON. For some strange reason some of the names are written with whitespaces making it difficult for me to declare variables that'll show the integer type value they  hold. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HhFj.png) . I am trying to parse the Int value attached to the type "Anti-social behaviour" but don't seem to know how to declare it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own `CodingKeys` inside the file. Note that the name should be `CodingKeys`.

```
struct Types: Codable {
    let buglary: Int
    let shoplifting: Int
    let drugs: Int
    let robbery: Int
    let antiSocialBehavior: Int

    // Other properties

    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case buglary = "Buglary"
        case shoplifting = "Shoplifting"
        case drugs = "Drugs"
        case robbery = "Robbery"
        case antiSocialBehavior = "Anti-social behavior"
        // other coding keys
    }
}
```

Also, note that properties in Swift are always camelcased and not capitalized. So, I also changed the name of your properties. Check the enum inside the struct which actually defines the mapping between property name and their encoding / decoding keys.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you I’ll try that